# SimpleXML failing to find namespaced elements

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I can't seem to get PHP's SimpleXML class to recognize prefixed namespace elements in an XHTML document. Here's my example:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:zuq="http://localhost/zuq">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <zuq:region name="myRegion">
        <div class="myClass">
            <h1><zuq:data name="myDataHeading" /></h1>
            <p><zuq:data name="myDataParagraph" /></p>
        </div>
    </zuq:region>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do the following:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file('test.html');
print_r($sxml);
```

It returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [head] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [meta] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [http-equiv] => Content-Type
                            [content] => text/html; charset=utf-8
                        )

                )

            [title] => Untitled Document
        )

    [body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [h1] => Heading
            [p] => Paragraph
        )

)
```

But when I do the following:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file('test.html');
$sxml_zuq = $sxml->children('zuq', true);
print_r($sxml_zuq);
```

It returns empty:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

Iterating through the object with `foreach` or otherwise doesn't seem to work, and using the URI rather than the prefix in `children()` also fails.

I've obviously made a mistake somewhere, but I'm not sure where, as my attempt is quite identical to many tutorial examples I've come across in my reading.

What's going on here?

Comment: If you use `SimpleXMLElement::getNamespaces()` do you get a result?

Comment: Yes I do **John Giotta**; However as Josh pointed out, children is only direct descendants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children()` only gives you the [direct] children of the context node, not descendants.

```
$html = simplexml_load_file('test.html');

// get <body/>'s children
$html->body->children('zuq', true);

// use XPath to get all zuq:* nodes
$html->xpath('//zuq:*');
```

Comment: **Josh Davis** saves the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for Info, in case the namespace definition , xmlns:zuq="http://localhost/zuq" was declared in the actual xml element instead of root node, then we have to additionally call registerXPathNamespace function and then use xpath as given in http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/09/30/xpath-in-simplexml/